# VBA application-defined or object-defined error for refreshing pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Hello I recorded a macro in excel to refresh these pivot tables that I want selected, however when I try to run the Macro it gives me this error "application-defined or object-defined error". I'm not really sure why it's working as all I did was hit record Macro, refreshed the tables I wanted and use this to refresh the tables specified.

```
Sub Refresh()
'
' Refresh Macro
'

'
    Sheets("F-Pivots").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("P-Pivots").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("F-Y-Reject P.").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("P-Y-Reject P.").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("F-Y-DT P.").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("P-Y-DT P.").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
    Sheets("Monthly Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=-1
    Sheets("Heatmap").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: In what line is the error raising?

Comment: The second line `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh`

Comment: When you right click that specific pivot table and hit refresh, does it work?

Comment: The thing is though sometimes the code does work, and goes through the function and does refresh the tables while other times it crashes. Sometimes it crashes on the second line but I just ran it again and it crashed on this line `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotCache.Refresh`. I have no idea why the error only appears sometimes.

Comment: Yes it does and when I recorded the macro in the first place and was refreshing the pivot tables they all worked then.

Comment: Double check the pivot table name in that sheet. is it correct?

Comment: Yes I can see in the Analyze tab under PivotTable Name: it is listed as "PivotTable1" just like in the VBA code. I checked for the other tables in the other sheets as well and they all have the same name as the ones being called on in the vba code.

Comment: Is `PivotTable100` in sheet `Monthly Data`?

Comment: Yes that pivot table is in the monthly data sheet and I can see it says "PivotTable100" under PivotTable Name in the Analyze tab.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that some of the pivot tables have the same name and are located in different sheets, so I believe something is wrong.

The following code refers to the `Pivot Tables` by their name and refreshes their cache. The cache (source data) should be refreshed by all tables using them.

**Code:**
**EDIT:** Use refresh table method on the PivotTable

```
Public Sub Refresh()

    Range("PivotTable1").PivotTable.RefreshTable
    Range("PivotTable2").PivotTable.RefreshTable
    Range("PivotTable3").PivotTable.RefreshTable
    Range("PivotTable100").PivotTable.RefreshTable

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Heatmap").Activate

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I stepped through it with F8 and it failed on this line in RefreshPivotTable function `targetPivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh` it gave the error "Application-Define or Object defined error"

Comment: If you place the mouse over the `targetPivotTableName`variable, what's the name of the Pivot Table?

Comment: If you can remove sensitive data, upload the file to google drive or onedrive and post the link here. I'll look into it.

Comment: targetPivotTable = "PivotTable1"

Comment: Thank you for the offer I really do appreciate it! Unfortunately my company has a strict file sharing policy and I am unable to upload anything from my work computer to a google drive or dropbox account :/

Comment: I just noticed that you have the same name for the pivot table in different sheets . See my new answer

Comment: ran the updated code and it says "Method 'Range' of 'object '_Global Failed' on the line `Range("PivotTable1").PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh` When I hover over the code it says targetPivotTableName = "PivotTable1"

Comment: do you have multiple files open? is the file you're running the macro the same as the one holding the pivot table? I'm certainly unable to reproduce your error.

Comment: The file itself is pulling the data from two other files and various other individuals have access to that file and are adding information to that file which is shared on a shared drive.On my computer however I only have one file open.

Comment: I really do appreciate your assistance! I tried the code from your edit and it still gave me the "Method 'Range' of 'object '_Global Failed' error on the first line of code. The thing is though sometimes the code I had before from the Macro did work but other times it didn't. Maybe because the file is pulling info from two other files that are constantly being updated that could affect it? They update the files several times a day but they always have it open.

Comment: isolate that part. Make sure source files are closed and try it again.

Comment: It's a pretty big production line and unfortunately it will take me awhile to get that to happen due to several different lines updating the report daily. I appreciate your help and hopefully I can get back to you as soon as I am able to get this approved.